# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election, moderators

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://android.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: In case anyone was confused by the sudden appearance of this, it turns out that our site is big enough to warrant additional moderators! :)

Comment: Cool: *moderator positions available: 2*

Comment: Well, my Nomination is in :) I think I may need to up my meta participation however...

Comment: Oh, nice! I for one welcome more Android overlords, erm, moderators :)

Comment: I added a System wide message for the election